# Generics and collections - method undefined for type

Tags: java, collections

I'm working on a project, and I'm slightly stuck on one aspect of it.  I need to create a class which can manipulate collections of instances of other classes.  As part of this, it creates a wrapper object for each instance which has to be able to not only hold the instance, but perform certain operations on it (including equals/hashcode).

So the constructor takes not only the wrapped object, but also a function object which caller tells us can perform these operations in the way desired (which may differ from the native behavior for the contained objects).

Incidentally, I know that what I'm describing here sounds like I'm reinventing part of the Collections framework, but I've simplified here.

```
public class MapWrapper<K,V> {
    private class KeyWrapper<K> {
        K key;
        public KeyWrapper(K key) {
            // ...
        }
    }
    private class ValueWrapper<V> {
        V value;
        public ValueWrapper(V value) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    // ...
    HashMap<KeyWrapper<K>, ValueWrapper<V>> map 
            = new HashMap<KeyWrapper<K>, ValueWrapper<V>> ();
    // ...
```

Everything seems to be okay so far, but I seem to be unable to add entries to my contained map:

```
    public MapWrapper (HashMap<K, V> map) {
        // ...
        map.put(new KeyWrapper<K>(key), new ValueWrapper<V>(val));
        // ...
    }
```

This fails compilation, with this message:

  *"The method put(K, V) in the type HashMap<K,V> is not applicable for the arguments (HashPlus.KeyWrapper, HashPlus.ValueWrapper)*

And I'm at a loss. Is this type erasure at work?  I wouldn't think so - it's all in the same compilation unit, and it's not dropping to `HashMap<Object,Object>` - it's dropping to `HashMap<K,V>`, which seems odd.

Thoughts?  Pointers to glaring omissions?

**Update and solution:**
Based on recommendations from several responders, I replaced the original "add" line with:

```
        this.map.put(new KeyWrapper<K>(key), new ValueWrapper<V>(val));
```

And this sorted my problem.  Note: one responder suggested that I don't need to parameterize KeyWrapper and ValueWrapper on the put line, but removing that yields "raw type" warnings, so I have left them in.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Are you using a modern IDE like Eclipse, Netbeans or Intelli-J?  If you were, you shouldn't get stuck on this type of problem because they offer method completion and you'd see the add() method doesn't exist.

Comment: But I'd also add we've all been there looking for the super-complicated reason for a problem, finding in the end it's something stupidly easy ;-)

Comment: D'oh!   In fact, I am using a modern IDE - specifically Eclipse... and I still missed it.  I thought it was a type issue.  Thanks.

Comment: -- Update: swapping put for add changed nothing except the text of the error message.

Comment: --Yet another update: adding sfussenegger's "this.map.put" sorted it, though I _do_ need to parameterize KeyWrapper and ValueWrapper.

Comment: Well, compiler warnings often depend on the used compiler (you may even configure them in). I reckon that Eclipse's (incremental) compiler tends to be smarter than javac sometimes and issues fewer warnings. However, in your case both should work without warnings. Check this example for details: http://pastebin.com/m22a3bf3a (tested with Eclipse JDT 3.5.1 and javac 1.6.0_16)

Comment: Pastebin is down right now, but I've realized that you meant I didn't need to parameterize the class definitions of KeyWrapper and ValueWrapper, and you're right.  I thought you meant I didn't need to parameterize the variable declarations of those types.  Thanks for getting back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. it's `put(..)` not `add(..)`
2. you're trying to add `KeyWrapper` and `ValueWrapper` to the map parameter, not the map field. Use `this.map.put(..)`
3. you don't need to parameterize `KeyWrapper` and `ValueWrapper`. `K` and `V` are already available through `MapWrapper`

Answer (score 5):

The error says it all. The method you’re looking for is called `put`, not `add`.